What are the thousands of worlds in Mistral's Meciendo?
Gabriela Mistral's poem Meciendo contains the following stanza:

Dios Padre sus miles de mundos
mece sin ruido.

The translation on LyricsTranslate goes as follows:

God, the Father, your thousands of worlds
swing silently.

Ursula K. Le Guin's translation is a bit different:

The Father rocks his thousand worlds
silent, mild.

(Selected Poems of Gabriela Mistral, translated by Ursula K. Le Guin. University of New Mexico Press, 2003, page 56.)
What are the "thousands of worlds" supposed to refer to?

The Lyrics Translate version is not very good. This is a cradle song: the mother rocks her baby, the sea rocks the waves, the wind rocks the wheat, and god rocks the world. No imperatives here!

@PeterShor Verbs don't have cases, so "mece" can't be in vocative case.

Why thousands of worlds and not one world? I think Mistral was aiming for parallelism. The sea rocks many thousands of waves. The wind rocks many thousands of wheat plants. And God rocks many thousands of worlds. As for what those worlds are, we have a plausible answer from M.A. Golding.

God the Father rocks his thousands of worlds silently. The Spanish is made more poetic by not being said like this: Dios Padre mece sin ruido sus miles de mundo. That's the normal order as opposed to this inverted order. sus is not yours or theirs.

The thousands of worlds could be be planets in our solar system, plus asteroids, plus moons, plus comets.  By the time she was writing thousands of asteroids and comets were known in addition to the few planets and moons which were known.
And of course the thousands of worlds could be the millions of stars then known to exist in space with whatever as yet undiscovered planets, moons, asteroids, & comets might be orbiting them.
And there is the possibility that the thousands of worlds might be thousands of universes, thousands of alternate universes.  However, I rather doubt that Gabriella Mistral would have become familiar with the science fiction concept of alternate universes by the time she wrote "Meciendo".
